# ModuleNotFoundError while Requirement already satisfied

Tags: python, pip, modulenotfounderror

[image]

I am losing my mind over this. could someone please help me understand what needs to be done in order for me to import external libraries properly? I have deleted all other versions of python. I don't know what to do. Thank you.

Comment: what is the output of `where pip3` and `where python`

Comment: Clearly the `pip` installation is not the one associated with the `python` installation that you're using to run scripts with. You'll need to either run the correct `pip` or run the correct `python`.

Comment: @AhmedAEK nothing. I'm on windows.

Comment: okay, you seem to be using powershell, what about `Get-Command python` and `Get-Command pip3`.

Comment: You ran "pip3 ...".  Run "python -m pip install pynput" instead. The concern is the "pip3" command does not appear to be part of the python 3.10 install you're trying to use. And BTW, the 32-bit install seems a little odd.

Comment: @AhmedAEK Powershell is so annoying. Sorry I didn't realize that was the problem. here is the output: C:\Users\gabew>where python
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\python.exe
C:\Users\gabew\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

C:\Users\gabew>where pip3
C:\Users\gabew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pip3.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. uninstall any python version on your system.
2. go to [python.org](https://www.python.org/) and download a version of python that suits you (preferably 64 bit if your system can handle it).
3. in the end of the installation make sure you tick the "add python to PATH" to allow programs to find it.
4. make sure you link it to the Vscode properly, [this page has some details](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial)

basically your `python` points to your msys installation and your `pip3` points to an old installation of some version of python ... installing a new version of python and adding it to path should fix it, but you might want to manually remove those old versions so they won't bother you in the future.